# I Dont know how can I get bookmark button in fire base

Tags: java, android, firebase

iam already did add bookmark in the firebase but i dont know how can i get it
[image]

reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("pagenumber");

```
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pagenumber = pdfView.getCurrentPage();
            reference.setValue(pagenumber);

            if (true) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "تم حفظ العلامة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "لم يتم حفظ العلامة", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data) and please also indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: I dont know how can i import json here so i added a Picture here its simple code

Comment: Do you only want to import a JSON file that contains that value, `pagenumber = 5`?

Comment: yes just that !

Comment: i want to get this value its very easy but i want it Intger

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, do you want to download it or upload it?

Comment: not upload or download i want get the Value in this case its =5 into variable in java

Comment: So what exactly would you like to get if `pagenumber == 5`?

Comment: On click button change variable value

Comment: So you want on a button click to change the value of pagenumber, only if it contains the value of 5? What is the new value?

Comment: Not only may be value eqal 2 so on click make value eqal 5

Comment: I'm sorry but I have a hard time understanding what you need.

Comment: Iam saving variable value this value is page number like add bookmark may the user add page number 3 so in firebase pagenumber=3 so i want retrive this value from firebase